# Add sheet to created workbook from another workbook

Tags: python, python-2.7, xlrd, xlsxwriter

I create new workbooks via xlsxwriter. In every of them I need to have formated header sheet, which is stored in another template workbook. I know it is impossible to do with xlsxwriter, coz I cannot open template workbook with this.

I thought to do that by xlrd, copy this sheet and then with xlsxwriter  write it to created workbook.
But is it possible? To use combination of those two libraries?

I know this question is without even any code, but I'm lame with python and if you could give me any advice or something to deal with my problem I will be gratefull.

Answer (score 2):

`xlrd` and `xlswriter` aren't really designed to work together. Consider switching to the [`pyopenxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/default/) library, which allows both reading and writing of spreadsheets and might allow you to do what you need quite easily.

Comment: Is it only for excel 2010? I use 2007 only

Comment: Oh dear, you  may be out of luck if you can't convert to `.xlsx` format

Comment: I have `.xlsx` format, I create this file with xlsxwriter and there is many formats, formulas. Don't know if it is possible to do with pyopenxl. Or maybe I'll save created file by xlsxwriter, then open it again by pyopenxl and the template from where I'll take a sheet to copy, and then copy it? Do you think it can work? The formats etc won't change?